# How to integrate Apache Superset Charts in Angular 7 application? Issue with Authentication and Headers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, apache-superset

I have charts built with Apache Superset. I need to integrate the chart in my Angular 7 application with iframe.

Major issue is I get authentication failure and error message stating **Refused to display 'http://[CHART-URL]' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'**.

How should I integrate the Apache Superset Chart to do things right way avoiding all these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Answer (score 2):

Add `HTTP_HEADERS = {}`  in the `superset_config.py` file. This would allow you add the chart with iframe.

Comment: I am new to Apache Superset, can you please let me know how to integrate superset with vue application? Thanks in advance!